# Why doesn't magnetomotive force have units of force?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, units

Why does it have units of Ampere-turns and not Newtons?

Is it a current, or turns mean metres?

Comment: See [Units of magnetizing force](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/174673/) and [What is the physical significance of the unit ampere/meter in magnetics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/94828/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, turns doesn't mean meters here.  Unfortunately, electromagnetics uses many bizarre units.  A force should be a force, not a current.  The correct units of magnetomotive force are weber/m or emu/cm, which dimensionally is t/s^2 x t/s, which in a sense means force times t/s, rather than the simple t/s^2 for other forces; this is because the magnetomotive force is actually two-dimensional, not one-dimensional, as are other forces. Study the Reciprocal System and prove it for yourself.